# How to Find number and folder of files in a directory

Tags: c, io, system-calls, stat, readdir

I need to find number of files and folders in a directory. I'm using MinGW compiler before this I tried to use d_type but I couldn't compile my code.

And I don't care about "." and" .. " directory. I don't wanna calculate them.

So I write a program like this. This program can easily find how many files and folders in a directory.

But When I give a new Name a folder instead of  New Folder, New Folder(1). This programs calculate that folders as a file.

What can I do? I really stuck. I have to find how many files and how many folders...

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {

int file_count = 0;
int dir_count = 0;
struct dirent * entry;
struct stat filestat;
size_t nfiles = 0, ndirs = 0;
DIR *dp;

if (argc != 2)
{
    printf("usage: put directory_name\n");
    exit(-1);
}


if ((dp = opendir(argv[1])) == NULL)
{
    printf("Error: can't open %s\n", argv[1]);
    exit(-2);
}

while ((entry= readdir(dp)) != NULL){

    if (!strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(entry->d_name, "..")) {
        continue;
    }

     stat(entry->d_name,&filestat);

    if( S_ISDIR(filestat.st_mode) ){
      ndirs++;
      }
    else
       nfiles++;
}

closedir(dp);

  printf("%lu Files, %lu Directories\n", nfiles, ndirs);

return(0);
 }
```

Comment: As I said before I couldn't use  d_type  and DT_REG.  I couldn't compile that codes on Windows.

Comment: Well, you did not say that explicitly.  But I have removed the links and close vote.

Answer (score 0):

`entry->d_name` will contain the filename only, not the full path, so if call `stat()` it will fail unless that file happens to exist in the current directory.

Also note that your code is not recursive, so it won't count stuff in the subfolders.

Comment: How can I fix?  I'm really stuck. I couldn't do anything. I have to make this program on Windows. I couldn't even use entry->d_type.

Comment: This helps to delineate part of the problem, but does not go too far in answering the question.  I am not down-voting, but this is the type of answer that may attract a few :)  Suggest placing this in comments unless you plan to flesh it out a little more.

Comment: I can understand. I'm beginner of programming also newbie on here.So I'm not good at both :) I just need help...